# Server shutdown in progress for hours

Tags: mysql

I have a relatively large database (> 500 GB), and have run a `yum update` last night, that upgraded `mysql-community-server`.

Since then, the MySQL server has been in "Server shutdown in progress" status for 16 hours now:

```
# service mysqld status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status mysqld.service
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) since Mon 2020-07-20 01:18:28 CEST; 14h ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
 Main PID: 8318 (mysqld)
   Status: "Server shutdown in progress"
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
           └─8318 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Plus, `mysqld` is now constantly using 300% CPU.

Is there a problem, or is this just a consequence of the database being large? Is there any way I can get some idea of the time left, or see what the server is actually doing?

And is there anything I can do to speed up the process?

For information, the server is a 6-core Xeon with 128GB RAM and NVMe drives, so rather fast.

There is plenty of available disk space and free RAM.

```
# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         128889       88292       11189        2225       29407       37145
Swap:         16381        5168       11213
```

---

**Update:** it's now been 72 hours. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Could you please add to the question the output of: `mysql -e "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS \G"` and `mysql -e "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST"|grep -vi sleep`

Comment: Make sure you have enough disk space: `df -h`

Comment: Check server usage: `top` `vmstat -w 5 3` `iostat -x 5 3`

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici The server is not started, so the `mysql` command fails with "Can't connect to local MySQL server". There is 300 GB free disk space. There is 38 GB RAM available. `iostat` shows some read/write, but not much (~5 /s).

Comment: You mentioned that mysqld is at 300% CPU usage. Is it still running? check with `ps -ef |grep mysql`

Comment: It's still running indeed!

Comment: You should be able to connect as root user or any user that is DBA.

Comment: If the MySQL server is not running (shutting down), you can obviously not connect to it. Or did I misunderstand what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, if it is not running you can't connect to it with `mysql` client. But it could happen that the mysql server is stuck and it is not accepting new connections, or it is accepting only administrative connections. Check if mysql listener is still up: `sudo ss -tlnp|grep :3306`

Comment: Can you provide the output of `free -m` and of the logfiles under `/var/log/mysql/`?

Comment: @shodanshok I added the output of `free -m` in the question. The last entries in `/var/log/mysqld.log` are `2020-07-19T23:18:30.471989Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 8729807  user: 'nicebooks'.` and a few similar others. They date back to the time of the update. There are no other `/var/log/mysql*` log files/dirs.

Comment: I'm assuming at this point you don't want to pull the plug and see what happens... What are the last modification times for your database files?  Can you get a stack trace of the process(es) that are still running, using `gstack`/`pstack`?  What do the running process(es) show if you attach to them with `strace -p PID`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems it's [known bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18256) and the reason why it happened because you haven't stopped database before the upgrade and some query was running.

You can find more details on [Percona article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/12/30/error-mysqld-sort-aborted-server-shutdown-in-progress/)

Try to use command line utility [mytop](https://www.tecmint.com/mytop-mysql-mariadb-database-performance-monitoring-in-linux/) to see what's going on. But you've mentioned you can't reach the database, try under root user. If it's possible make a backup of the database, if you can't in worse case you try to repair the DB using commands in [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rebuilding-tables.html)

In this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1420699/how-to-fix-mariadb-when-it-gets-stuck-during-shutdown-waiting-for-page-cleaner) is suggestion it's may related to the time settings on your server.

To obtain information about the stuck process you may use `lsof -c mysqld` should give you hint.

Instead of killing the mysqld process rather try to restart the server from command `systemctl reboot` or `shutdown -r now`, don't pull it out of the plug.

Comment: I was a bit reluctant a first to restart the server, but... it just worked! The MySQL server is now up and running. I ran `mysqlcheck` and all tables are `OK`. I'm surprised by your statement, though: "it happened because you haven't stopped database before the upgrade and some query was running". I have a lot of queries running all the time, and never stopped the database server before the upgrade. Shouldn't `yum` take care of stopping the MySQL server before the upgrade?

Comment: Well, when there isn't any activity on DB service you can upgrade it and nothing will happen. But usually you don't want any connections to database during the update/upgrade, as it can kill the query in the middle so the transaction will hang. Correct is to stop the DB server before the upgrade or kill the connections to it, one of the ways is temporarily change the password in web app so it can't connect, or stop the httpd/apache/nginx. Simply when something is writing to it, it can go wrong.Better safe than sorry :)